# Subtract one array of arrays from another ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have an array of months and amounts like so...

```
a = [[9, 2336.02], [8, 7993.6], [7, 5265.73], [6, 7075.33], [5, 9281.02], [4, 9524.64], [3, 300]]
```

I then have another like so...

```
b = [[9, 2817.61], [8, 7033.74], [7, 5650.73], [6, 9206.72], [5, 8554.24], [4, 6682.1], [3, 2211.84]]
```

I need to subtract the amounts in array a from the amounts in array b while keeping the keys. So my output should look like

```
c = [[9,-481.59], [8, 959.86],[...]]
```

I tried

```
a.each_with_index.map { |month, amount| amount - b.each { |months,cost| cost }
```

But can't seem to get it right. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @jordan, you are correct sorry. Its been a long day

Comment: You mean subtract the amounts in array `b` from those in `a` to be consistent with `c`.

Comment: Do the months always have the same index in both arrays?

Comment: @stefan, yes they do

Comment: You still need to reverse `a` and `b` in "I need to subtract the amounts in array `a` from the amounts in array `b`" to be consistent with `c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `zip`

```
c = a.zip(b).map{|k| [k[0][0], (k[0][1] - k[1][1]).round(2)] }
#=> [[9, -481.59], [8, 959.86], [7, -385.0], [6, -2131.39], [5, 726.78], [4, 2842.54], [3, -1911.84]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You weren't far off, but in your attempt you forgot to actually use the index.

You probably meant to do something like this:

```
a.each_with_index.map {|(month, amount), i| [ month, amount - b[i][1] ] }
```

We can make this a bit more "Rubyish" with [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
a.zip(b).map {|(month, amount_a), (_, amount_b)| [ month, amount_a - amount_b ] }
```

Comment: This zip method is giving me this output  `[[[9, 2336.02], -2817.61], [[8, 7993.6], -7032.74], [[7, 5265.73], -5648.73], [[6, 7075.33], -9203.72], [[5, 9281.02], -8550.24], [[4, 9524.64], -6677.1], [[3, 300], -2205.84]]`

Comment: Also the each_with_index produced `[[[9, 2336.02], -2817.61], [[8, 7993.6], -7032.74], [[7, 5265.73], -5648.73], [[6, 7075.33], -9203.72], [[5, 9281.02], -8550.24], [[4, 9524.64], -6677.1], [[3, 300], -2205.84]]` which isnt right

Comment: Oops! yep I had something added onto a. Great!

Comment: #3: `a.each_index.map {|i| [ a[i][0], a[i][1] - b[i][1] ] }`.

Comment: The way you expressed the block variables in the `zip` method makes it much easier to read when compared to having only one (or two) block variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.

```
[a,b].transpose.map(&:transpose).map { |(e,_),arr| [e, arr.reduce(:-)] }
  #=> [[9, -481.59000000000015], [8, 959.8600000000006], [7, -385.0],
  #    [6, -2131.3899999999994], [5, 726.7800000000007], [4, 2842.539999999999],
  #    [3, -1911.8400000000001]]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
c = [a,b].transpose
  #=> [[[9, 2336.02], [9, 2817.61]], [[8, 7993.6], [8, 7033.74]],
  #    [[7, 5265.73], [7, 5650.73]], [[6, 7075.33], [6, 9206.72]],
  #    [[5, 9281.02], [5, 8554.24]], [[4, 9524.64], [4, 6682.1]],
  #    [[3, 300], [3, 2211.84]]] 
d = c.map(&:transpose)
  #=> [[[9, 9], [2336.02, 2817.61]], [[8, 8], [7993.6, 7033.74]],
  #    [[7, 7], [5265.73, 5650.73]], [[6, 6], [7075.33, 9206.72]],
  #    [[5, 5], [9281.02, 8554.24]], [[4, 4], [9524.64, 6682.1]],
  #    [[3, 3], [300, 2211.84]]] 
d.map { |(e,_),arr| [e, arr.reduce(:-)] }
  #=> [[9, -481.59000000000015], [8, 959.8600000000006], [7, -385.0],
  #    [6, -2131.3899999999994], [5, 726.7800000000007], [4, 2842.539999999999],
  #    [3, -1911.8400000000001]]
```

Let's examine the last calculation more closely.

```
enum = d.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[[9, 9], [2336.02, 2817.61]], [[8, 8], [7993.6, 7033.74]],
  #                  [[7, 7], [5265.73, 5650.73]], [[6, 6], [7075.33, 9206.72]],
  #                  [[5, 5], [9281.02, 8554.24]], [[4, 4], [9524.64, 6682.1]],
  #                  [[3, 3], [300, 2211.84]]]:map>
```

The first element generated by the enumerator is passed to the block and assigned to the block variables.

```
(e,_),arr = enum.next
  #=> [[9, 9], [2336.02, 2817.61]] 
e #=> 9
_ #=> 9
arr
  #=> [2336.02, 2817.61] 
arr.reduce(:-)
  #=> -481.59000000000015
```

so the array `[9, -481.59000000000015]` is returned.

The remaining calculations are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
(0...a.size).map { |i| [a[i].first, a[i].last - b[i].last] }
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks Cary for the Welcome!  Been busy with work. I may still not be that active as I was during last quarter of 2015, will apparate occassionally